# How to handle "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' "?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to access a table on a SQL Server using the Python 2.7 module adodbapi, and print certain information to the command prompt (Windows). Here is my original code snippet:

```
query_str = "SELECT id, headline, state, severity FROM GPS3.Defect ORDER BY id"

cur.execute(query_str)
dr_data = cur.fetchall()
con.close()

for i in dr_data:
    print i
```

It will print out about 30 rows, all correctly formatted, but then it will stop and give me this:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 52: oridinal not in range(128)
```

So I looked this up online and went through the presentation explaining Unicode in Python, and I thought I understood. So I would explicitly tell the Python
interpreter that it was dealing with Unicode, and should encode it into UTF-8. 
This is what i came up with:

```
for i in dr_data:
    print (u"%s"%i).encode('utf-8')
```

However, I suppose I don't actually understand Unicode because I get the same exact error when I run this. I know this question is asked a lot, but could someone explain to me, simply, what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `type(i)`? Its likely `str` not `unicode` but it matters in the explanation.

Comment: Also, did you get the same error on the second try or did you get a decode error instead of an encode error?

Comment: `type(i)` gives `<class 'adodbapi.apibase.SQLrow'>`, and I get the same exact error both times

Comment: Seeing the full error message dump would be more helpful than just the last line. Is the error occurring inside a library somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Your error message does not agree with the statement that you are printing on a Windows command prompt.  It does not default to the `ascii` codec.  On US Windows, it defaults to `cp437`.

You can just print Unicode to the console without trying to encode it.  Python will encode the Unicode strings to the console encoding.  Here is an example.  Note the *source file* is saved in UTF-8 encoding, and the encoding is declared with the special `#coding:utf8` comment.  This allows any Unicode character to be in the source code.

```
#coding:utf8
s1 = u'αßΓπΣσµτ'    # cp437-supported
s2 = u'ÀÁÂÃÄÅ'      # cp1252-supported
s3 = u'我是美国人。' # unsupported by cp437 or cp1252.
```

Since my US Windows console default to `cp437`, only `s1` will display without error.

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 437

C:\>py -2 -i test.py
>>> print s1
αßΓπΣσµτ
>>> print s2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
>>> print s3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Note the error message indicates what encoding it tried to use: `cp437`.

If I change the console encoding, now `s2` will work correctly:

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>py -2 -i test.py
>>> print s1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u03b1' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
>>> print s2
ÀÁÂÃÄÅ
>>> print s3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to <undefined>
```

Now `s3` contains characters that common Western encodings don't support.  You can go into Control Panel and change the system locale to Chinese and the console will then support Chinese encodings, but a better solution is to use a Python IDE that supports UTF-8, an encoding that supports all Unicode characters (subject to font support, or course).  Below is the output of PythonWin, an editor that comes with the `pywin32` Python extension:

```
>>> print s1
αßΓπΣσµτ
>>> print s2
ÀÁÂÃÄÅ
>>> print s3
我是美国人。
```

In summary, just use Unicode strings, and ideally use a terminal with UTF-8 and it will "just work".  Convert text data to Unicode as soon as it is read from file, user input, network socket, etc.  Process and print in Unicode, but encode it when it leaves the program (write to file, network socket, etc.).